# How to revert "git pull" changes in local folder without affecting remote repo?

Tags: git

I am on the branch `origin/develop` and did `git pull` in order to update my local repo. However, this last project version that I pulled from `develop` branch had a bug and now I cannot run the tool in my laptop.

How can I revert this pull request to the previous version, but without affecting the remote repo? I just want to step back to the previous version that I had in my laptop and that was working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the SHA-1 of a commit you want to go back to, and use:
git checkout SHA-1

Optionnaly you can give -b branch-name to create a branch from that commit, and not being "headless".